# Cut each N symbol from array

Tags: ruby

What is the most efficient and productive way to cut each N symbol from a string?

For instance,

> n = 5;
>
> str = '1234A1234B1234C';
>
> result: "123412341234"

This is my approach:

```
def delete_each_n(str, n)
  i = n

  str.length/n.times do
    str.slice!(i-1)
    i += (n - 1)
  end

  str
end
```

Comment: Would you mind adding some test cases? I just tried with your method, and got `delete_each_n("abcabc", 2) #=> "acbc"`, when I expected that you wanted "acb".

Comment: @thesecretmaster: It's a bug. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks @EricDuminil. You've written a much better answer than I have (so +1), but I'm still going to leave mine there as a different way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in performance, and your particular circumstances restrict the characters in the string to those in the ASCII range, then there is something to be said for avoiding the overhead of multibyte character operations and assuming single byte operations will work for you.

This is 2.4.2 on a MacBook Pro, and you'll see that method 4, using `bytesize` and `byteslice`, and avoiding `regexp` and `map`, is twice as fast as the next fastest on longer strings, and five times as fast on the original example.

```
2.4.2 :001 > def method1(string, n)
2.4.2 :002?>     string.gsub(/.{#{n}}/){ |sub| sub.chop }
2.4.2 :003?>   end
 => :method1 
2.4.2 :004 > 
2.4.2 :005 >   def method2(string, index)
2.4.2 :006?>     # Here I use a regular expression to split the string every n characters
2.4.2 :007 >       substrings = string.split(%r{(.{#{index}})})
2.4.2 :008?>       .reject(&:empty?) # And cut out any empty strings that appear
2.4.2 :009?>   
2.4.2 :010 >       # Then we can merge the substrings together, without the list character in each substring
2.4.2 :011 >       substrings.map do |substring|
2.4.2 :012 >           substring.length < index ? substring : substring[0..-2]
2.4.2 :013?>       end.join
2.4.2 :014?>   end
 => :method2 
2.4.2 :015 > 
2.4.2 :016 >   def method3(string, index)
2.4.2 :017?>     string.gsub(/(.{#{index-1}})./, '\\1')
2.4.2 :018?>   end
 => :method3 
2.4.2 :019 > 
2.4.2 :020 >   def method4(string, n)
2.4.2 :021?>     length = n - 1
2.4.2 :022?>     (0..(string.bytesize / n)).each_with_object("") do |x, new_string|
2.4.2 :023 >           new_string << string.byteslice(x*n, length)
2.4.2 :024?>       end
2.4.2 :025?>   end
 => :method4 
2.4.2 :026 > 
2.4.2 :027 >   require 'benchmark'
 => true 
2.4.2 :028 > 
2.4.2 :029 >   runs = 100000
 => 100000 
2.4.2 :030 > Benchmark.bm(7) do |x|
2.4.2 :031 >       string = '1234A1234B1234C'
2.4.2 :032?>     n      = 5
2.4.2 :033?>     x.report("method 0")   { runs.times {}}
2.4.2 :034?>     x.report("method 1")   { runs.times {method1(string, n)}}
2.4.2 :035?>     x.report("method 2")   { runs.times {method2(string, n)}}
2.4.2 :036?>     x.report("method 3")   { runs.times {method3(string, n)}}
2.4.2 :037?>     x.report("method 4")   { runs.times {method4(string, n)}}
2.4.2 :038?>   end ; ""
              user     system      total        real
method 0  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.003366)
method 1  0.570000   0.000000   0.570000 (  0.572950)
method 2  0.670000   0.000000   0.670000 (  0.666871)
method 3  0.750000   0.000000   0.750000 (  0.763856)
method 4  0.120000   0.000000   0.120000 (  0.118647)
 => "" 
2.4.2 :039 > 
2.4.2 :040 >   runs = 50000
 => 50000 
2.4.2 :041 > Benchmark.bm(7) do |x|
2.4.2 :042 >       string = '1234A1234B1234C'*50
2.4.2 :043?>     n      = 2
2.4.2 :044?>     x.report("method 0")   { runs.times {}}
2.4.2 :045?>     x.report("method 1")   { runs.times {method1(string, n)}}
2.4.2 :046?>     x.report("method 2")   { runs.times {method2(string, n)}}
2.4.2 :047?>     x.report("method 3")   { runs.times {method3(string, n)}}
2.4.2 :048?>     x.report("method 4")   { runs.times {method4(string, n)}}
2.4.2 :049?>   end ; ""
              user     system      total        real
method 0  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001685)
method 1  7.110000   0.010000   7.120000 (  7.131064)
method 2 11.450000   0.010000  11.460000 ( 11.475658)
method 3  9.640000   0.070000   9.710000 (  9.721599)
method 4  3.750000   0.010000   3.760000 (  3.758784)
 => "" 
2.4.2 :050 >
```

Answer (score 3):

## Your code

You have a sneaky bug in your code!

```
1000/2.times {|i| puts i }
```

You seem to think that this code would display 500 numbers between `0` and `499`.
It doesn't. Instead, it displays `0`, `1`, and returns `500`.

You need to replace `str.length/n.times do` with `(str.length/n).times do`.

## Alternative

You can use [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) to look for the substrings, [`chop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-chop) them and replace them:

```
def delete_every_nth_char(string, n)
  string.gsub(/.{#{n}}/){ |sub| sub.chop }
end

delete_every_nth_char('1234A1234B1234C', 5)
# "123412341234"
delete_every_nth_char('ABAB', 2)
# "AA"
delete_every_nth_char('ABA', 2)
# "AA"
delete_every_nth_char('ABA', 1)
# ""
delete_every_nth_char('ABA', 5)
# "ABA"
```

It is concise and probably faster than splitting and joining the strings manually.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to split the string into substrings that are the length `n`, then remove the last element from each substring. So, for example:

```
def delete_each_n(string, index)
  # Here I use a regular expression to split the string every n characters
  substrings = string.split(%r{(.{#{index}})})
    .reject(&:empty?) # And cut out any empty strings that appear

  # Then we can merge the substrings together, without the list character in each substring
  substrings.map do |substring|
    substring.length < index ? substring : substring[0..-2]
  end.join
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be:

```
 str.gsub(/(.{#{n-1}})./, '\\1')
```

Comment: I think you should explain why your alternative is better.